# Login page issues while using react js and Django api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, api

I am creating a simple login page using react js and Django api. I am able to login but unable to go to my dashboard as it is throwing error like "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"
I am using Visual Studio Code

The full code is as below:

**Login.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

import { setUserSession } from './Utils/Common';


function Login(props) {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const username = useFormInput('');

  const password = useFormInput('');

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);


  // handle button click of login form

  const handleLogin = () => {

    setError(null);

    setLoading(true);

    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/account/user/signin', { mobile_number: username.value, 

password: password.value }).then(response => {

      setLoading(false);

      setUserSession(response.data.token, response.data.user);

      props.history.push('/dashboard');

    }).catch(error => {

      setLoading(false);

      if (error.response.status === undefined) setError(error.response.data.message);

      else setError("Something went wrong. Please try again later.");

    });

  }


  return (

    <div>

      Login<br /><br />

      <div>

        Username<br />

        <input type="text" {...username} autoComplete="new-password" />

      </div>

      <div style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>

        Password<br />

        <input type="password" {...password} autoComplete="new-password" />

      </div>

      {error && <><small style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</small><br /></>}<br />

      <input type="button" value={loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Login'} onClick={handleLogin} 
disabled={loading} /><br />

    </div>

  );
}

const useFormInput = initialValue => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);


  const handleChange = e => {

    setValue(e.target.value);

  }
  return {
    value,
    onChange: handleChange

  }
}

export default Login;
```

**Dashboard.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

import { getUser, removeUserSession } from './Utils/Common';

function Dashboard(props) {

  const user = getUser();

  //handle click event of logout button

  const handleLogout = () => {

    removeUserSession();

    props.history.push('/login');

  }

  return (

    <div>

     Welcome {user.name}!<br /><br />

    <input type="button" onClick={handleLogout} value="Logout" />

    </div>

  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```